# How to i read field data from firestore in react native?

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the temp value in application from fire store but I don't know how to do it by using hook (온도 means temperature)
please help me this is my code.                                                                                                                                                 v                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                v

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Iconicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import firestore, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View} 
  from 'react-native';
  
  const temp = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.top}>
        <View style={styles.array}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.pop()}}>
            <Iconicons name={'arrow-back-outline'} size={40}  color={'white'}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.word}>온도</Text>
            <Text>          </Text>
            </View>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>온도:{temp} </Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    flex: 1,
    
  },
  top:{
    backgroundColor: '#007ccc',
    flex: 1,
  },
  body:{
    marginTop:100,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
  word:{
    fontSize:20,
    color:'white',
  },
  array:{
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    flexDirection:'row',
  },
  box:{
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor:'white',
    borderRadius:30,
    width:300,
    height:300,
  },
  text:{
    fontSize:50,
  },
});

export default temp;
```

This is my data from firestore:

[image: this is my data from firestore]

[image]

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If so, could you please update the question to show your current situation / errors that you are receiving?